# Converting strings to numbers in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, numbers

I have a cell array of numbers (in string format) which I would like to convert to numbers in matlab. The thing is that they are double quoted and I cannot seem to use str2num to convert them.

```
a = {'"15"'; '"16"'; '"17"'; '"30"'; '"50"'}
```

Is there any way to do so or to remove the double quotations from the numbers? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually remove the double-quote symbols. You can do that using [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to each cell. Here are two possible ways:

1. The anonymous function simply *strips off the first and last characters*. This works if the double-quote symbols are always at those positions:

   ```
   a = {'"15"'; '"16"'; '"17"'; '"30"'; '"50"'};
   result = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x(2:end-1)), a);
   ```
2. If some strings may not contain the double-quote symbols, or may contain several in arbitrary positions, use an anonymous function that *removes any occurrences of that symbol*:

   ```
   a = {'15'; '16'; '"17"'; '30"'; '"""50"""'};
   result = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x(x~='"')), a);
   ```

Comment: using [regexp](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) is a little bit faster and maybe a somewhat more robust solution `result = cellfun(@str2double, regexp(a, '\d+\.?\d*', 'match'))`

Comment: @serial Good idea. However, the regex would to be modified if there may be negative numbers or things like `.123` (without leading `0`)

Comment: @LuisMendo that's right: `'(+|-)?\d*\.?\d*'` let's hope the input data is not that bad ;)